# concatenate rows for many conditions

Tags: t-sql

I need to concatenate the rows(taille). for example, for the code_commande 001 and code_article=1, I need to concatenate in list all taille which have these two conditions. another example, for code_commande=001 and code_article=2, the same job I need to concatenate in a list all taille which have these two conditions. this for all

```
code_commande   code_article    taille
001                  1          s         
001                  1          m         
001                  1          xl        
001                  1          x52       
001                  2          m         
001                  1          5566      
001                  2          x52       
001                  1          xl        
002                  1          s         
002                  2          m         
001                  3          xxl       
002                  3          xs        
001                  1          ml        
001                  1          xs32
```

I need to concatenate taille for each code_commande for each code_article
example of result:

```
001            1             s,m,xl etcc
```

dynamically

I should have a table who grouped the ( taille) for each code_commande for each code_article like:

```
001                    1                  s,m,xl,
001                    2                  s,xl,l 
002                    1                  xs,ettcc
```

I have tried this query but ,it concatenate all (taille) for all rows
the query

```
Select  [code_commande],[code_article], SUBSTRING( 
(
     SELECT  ',' +[taille]  AS 'data()' 
         FROM [dbo].[commande] FOR XML PATH('') 
), 2 , 9999) As taille_commande
from [dbo].[commande] 
order by [code_article],[code_commande]desc
```

Comment: Explain what you have done and why it does not work.

Comment: i need to have table that's have all (tailles) ordered by code_commande and code article        exemple : for code_commande 1 and code_article 1 i need have all tailles concatenated and for code_commande 1 and article 2 i need have all tailles etttc

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [Ask]. Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: i need a query who returns this

Comment: Well I need a brand new Ferrari. Think we can trade? Stackoverflow is not a free coding service. You are expected to show your efforts at solving the problem at hand.

Comment: You can use  [`STRING_AGG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, `STRING_AGG()` is your friend for this requirement. Assuming your original post contained the schema you're working with, a simple aggregate query will give you the results you want.

```
select code_commande, code_article, STRING_AGG(taille, ',') as taille_commande
from dbo.commande
group by code_commande, code_article
```

[STRING_AGG reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Note this is only available in SQL Server 2017+ and azure. To see a possible solution for previous versions, see [this duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/how-to-concatenate-text-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-text-string-in-sql-serv).